# How can I solve this error :Record not found cannot copy?

Tags: python, odoo

I want to duplicate applicant attachment to a custom module candidat_base I got this error :
  Enregistrement #63 de candidat.base non trouv\xe9, copie impossible
  (English: record not found cannot copy)

```py
def _application2(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context=None):
    app_obj = self.pool.get('hr.applicant')
    Attachment = self.pool.get('ir.attachment')
    app_id = {}
    for cand in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        app_id = app_obj.search(cr, uid, [('email_from', 'like', cand.email_candidat)], context=context)
    attachment_ids = Attachment.search(cr, uid, [('res_model', '=', 'hr.applicant'), ('res_id', 'in', app_id)], context=context)
    for attachment in Attachment.browse(cr, uid, attachment_ids, context=context):
        Attachment.copy(cr, uid, attachment.id, default={'name': attachment.name}, context=context)
    return True
```

Comment: Please provide the error message in english. Shouldn't it be `Attachment.copy(..)` within your last for loop?

Comment: the error is : record not found cannot copy

Comment: As i've already written: you are using `self.pool.get('ir.attachment')` but arent't using it for copy(). Don't you want to copy an attachment?

Comment: yes I want to copy attachment from applicant to my new module . I have used Attachment.copy(...) but I still have the same problem

Comment: Could you please update your code?

Comment: Can you try to debug the second for each loop? Somethings seems wrong there. Does `attachment` always has an `id`?